# How to get number format and locale string from given number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, localization

I have a string containing a number, like

```
var number = "$1,344";
```

I need to identify the number format as currency and the localization language by the currency symbol (English in this case, for `"$"`). Can I get this using any logic in JavaScript or jQuery?

Note: I need to do this without using any third party plugin/script.

Comment: So you want to take something like "$1,344" and get "US" from that?

Comment: @FrankerZ - he wants currency symbol to language, not currency symbol to cuntry.

Comment: Well, you should check if your "number" (a string, actually) contains `"$"`, then if it contains `"€"`, then others.. you have to gather currency symbols (or may be currency codes http://www.xe.com/iso4217.php and convert them to symbols) to check all of them.

Comment: I have to get the what locale that strings holds and format like currency, exponential @FrankerZ

Answer (score 0):

This probably isn't possible. The reason is that many countries, which speak different languages, might use the same currency symbol.

- The [Euro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eurozone) (`€`) is used in 23 countries, which together have
  official languages such as Dutch, English, French, German, Irish,
  Maltese, Slovak, Slovene, Spanish, and dozens of other local
  languages.
- The [dollar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dollar#Economies_that_use_a_dollar) (`$`) is a generic currency name. There's the US
  Dollar, East Caribbean Dollar, Fijian Dollar, New Taiwan Dollar, and
  dozens more. Dollar using nations have dozens of languages, not just
  English.
- The [rupee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupee) is used in India, Indonesia, Nepal, and more. There's hundreds of languages in Rupee using countries. Even if we restrict this to just the Indian Rupee (I believe no other currency has the symbol `₹`), there's still many languages to choose from.

I could give more examples for almost every single currency symbol.

I don't think there's a logical way to go from currency symbols to languages. It's not even close to a one-to-one mapping.

Localization is hard.